# Rules in Neural network

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

There are some rules in Neural network

A: The neurons in input layer mast be same as number of input features

The batch size is the one that feed into the model from first loop of the training data. So, the neurons should be equal to the batch size. Why it is equal to the number of input features.

I also checked that giving random number of neurons to input layer will work.

B: How to predict a good model
For example, In regression problem- I have loss as mse and validation loss. The validation loss will be little higher than loss for a good model (as I read from research gate question and answer). But how much varriation will be good.

Thank you

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `python` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: @desertnaut, I did not post spam information. I am using neural net in python. So, I thought that python tag will also help.

Comment: Understood. For the future, please notice that tags should be related only to the *content* of the question, and not its *context*.

Answer (score 0):

A: The number of neurons in your networks first layer doesn't have to be equal to the batch size or the number of features. If you have more neurons in your model, then your model has higher complexity.

B:There are many ways to measure the performance of the models. One way is to split our dataset into training and validation sets. Then, we train our network on training data. During the training we measure a loss metric like MSE (Mean Squared Error) on both training and validation sets. Once we plot loss/epochs for both sets, we can interpret the figure to see if the model is properly trained.